What is the name of this (Prince of pearl?) movie?
It's an old movie released somewhere in 90's and the language probably not English, seen it on TV.

I remember the name as Prince of pearl but I cant find the movie by that name
Language is not English I remember like french.
There was a handsome captain who's hand is attached to his body which the cut mark is still there.
Captain goes to a beautiful island or ship wracked and swam to the island
The island captain swam to is a Hawaiian island as I remember, there is this 
Hawaiian sort of people.
Island's people believes a hero who's arm is cut coming to rescue if they are in danger
Captain friends with island's royal family.
This island have valuable pearls something about royal pearl necklace. 
Captain finds out about the prince of pearl island and his mother which is also a beautiful lady. 
Story goes on at the end of the movie prince's mother and captain goes to an edge of a cliff to get married and something about the necklace and they snaps out to the future or I remember like that. 

I can remember some action seen before movie ends, captain goes in side a cave in the sea kind of like a blow hole and he found something there, pearls may be not sure the cave located directly below the sea at the end someone blows the cave and sea water comes in, I can remember sort of like raining pearls.
I really love to see it again I can't find the movie anywhere on earth and I apologize if my English makes you dizzy.

Welcome, Please try to add details like Country, language, approximate year of release and movie released in theaters or made for TV, where did you see it.

I think movie released somewhere in 90's. That's all I can remember the language probably not English.

oh! I see it on TV

If you remember anymore details, Please use the edit button and add them to question. Thanks.

Yes that's it,that's the movie thanx Richard.

Richard I upvoted your answer but I accidentally undo it, Says I cannot upvoted it back if I undo it. I wanted to accept your answer how to do that?

@USERP I don't see any answers.

@Richard - Sure
